# How do I increase the font and icon size of the files and folders in the project navigator area

Tags: xcode

I understand how to increase the font size pertaining of the text editor using the font and colour option within Xcode 7.2 preferences for my swift project but I would like to increase the font and icon size specifically for the files and folders in the project navigator area which looks smallish on the eye.

How is this achieved.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change your device screen resolution to accomplish this.  Otherwise, there are no known solutions.